# Npgsql.NpgsqlException: ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "where"

Tags: asp.net, web-services, postgresql, npgsql, postgresql-9.2

I have the followinf web service in asp.net

```
//setup profile
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void SetProfile(string userName, string firstName, string lastName, string imageUrl)
    {
        //create and open connection
        NpgsqlConnection profileConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PrevueConnString"].ToString());
        profileConnection.Open();

        //create query and command
        string query = "INSERT into \"Users\" (\"FirstName\", \"LastName\", \"ImageUrl\") values(:fname, :lname, :imageUrl) where \"UserName\" = :user";
        NpgsqlCommand profileCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(query, profileConnection);

        profileCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("user", DbType.String));
        profileCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("fname", DbType.String));
        profileCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("lname", DbType.String));
        profileCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("imageUrl", DbType.String));

        profileCommand.Parameters[0].Value = userName;
        profileCommand.Parameters[1].Value = firstName;
        profileCommand.Parameters[2].Value = lastName;
        profileCommand.Parameters[3].Value = imageUrl;

        int result = profileCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        profileCommand.Dispose();
        profileConnection.Close();

        string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Context.Response.Flush();
        Context.Response.Write(json);
    }
```

On invoking the web service, I get the following error:

Npgsql.NpgsqlException: ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "where"

Comment: Please show the final SQL that's generated and sent by nPgSQL to the database. You can get this from the PostgreSQL server logs. You might need to set `log_statement = 'all'`.

Comment: Hey Craig, I guess i figured out the error, i used the 'Where' clause with an Insert command, changed that to Update and things are smooth now... :) Appreciate your help..!!

Comment: Wow ... I'm so embarrassed that I didn't spot that. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess i figured out the error, i used the 'Where' clause with an Insert command, changed that to Update and things are smooth now... :) Appreciate your help..!!